# reading from cmd.StdoutPipe()

Tags: go

Please consider this Go code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

const (
    debugCmd = "/usr/bin/libinput debug-events"
    //debugCmd = "tail -f /tmp/syslog"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello!")
    fmt.Println("cmd", debugCmd)
    cmdSplat := strings.Split(debugCmd, " ")
    cmd := exec.Command(cmdSplat[0], cmdSplat[1:]...)
    stdOut, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("cmd.StdOut failed", err)
    }
    defer stdOut.Close()

    go func() {
        tempBuf := make([]byte, 1024)
        for {
            n, err := stdOut.Read(tempBuf)
            if n > 0 {
                fmt.Printf("Read: %d bytes, err: %v\n", n, err)
                someSlice := tempBuf[:n]
                fmt.Println("text", string(someSlice))
            } else {
                fmt.Printf("Zero Read :%d, err: %v", n, err)
            }

        }
    }()

    fmt.Println("STarting cmd")
    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("cmd.start", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("All done!")
    // cmd.Wait()
    time.Sleep(60 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("Done sleeping!")

}
```

In real life, it is picking up only after it reads 1024 bytes. Earlier I had this using bufio, but that was slow too:

```
go func() {
    r := bufio.NewReader(stdOut)
    for {
        line, err := r.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("End of things!")
            break
        }
        fmt.Print(line)

    }
}()
```

My objective is to pickup `debug-events` from `stdOut io.ReadCloser` reasonably fast - as they occur and appear - instead of batches with a watermark of 1024 bytes.

Here's my output:

```
Read: 1024 bytes, err: <nil> // <------------ this 
text finger)
 event5   POINTER_AXIS     +2.380s  vert -11.14/0* horiz 10.75/0* (finger)
 event5   POINTER_AXIS     +2.400s  vert -8.97/0* horiz 6.54/0* (finger)
 <snip>
 event5   POINTER_AXIS     +3.219s  vert 7.42/0* horiz 0.00/0 (finger)
 event5   POINTER_AXIS 
Read: 1024 bytes, err: <nil> // <-------------- this 
text     +3.238s    vert 9.28/0* horiz -15.89/0* (finger)
 event5   POINTER_AXIS     +3.257s  vert 8.66/0* horiz -17.29/0* (finger)
 event5   POINTER_AXIS     +3.277s  vert 7.42/0* horiz -11.69/0* (finger) 
 <snip>
 event5   POINTER_AXIS     +3.491s  vert 0.00/0* horiz 0.00/0* (finger)
 event5   POINTER_MOTION   +3
Read: 1024 bytes, err: <nil>
text .980s   -0.23/ -0.90 ( -1.00/ -3.97)
```

Could you point me the correct way please?

Comment: Typically the problem here is not in your own code at all, but rather in the program you are invoking, which chooses not to *send* you output until it has accumulated some buffer-full of text—in this case, 1024 bytes at a time. The trick then is to somehow coax *that program* to behave in the way you would prefer. These programs often check whether their output is going to a "tty" (using the C language `isatty` function, or `IsTerminal` from https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal for instance.

Comment: If that's the case, using a pseudo-tty ("pty") can help. Sometimes it's a lot easier though: some programs have a command line argument or environment variable that makes them behave well. There are multiple Go packages for providing ptys. I have no idea which ones are the best, but here is a simple-looking one: https://github.com/google/goterm

Comment: Thanks, will try. If i run `/usr/bin/libinput debug-events` on the terminal, stdout is immediate. This is what I am trying to emulate - https://github.com/iberianpig/fusuma/blob/master/lib/fusuma/libinput_command.rb#L42 in go.

Comment: Based on the documentation, Ruby's `Open3.popen3` just uses pipes (not ptys). Note though the `prefix = 'stdbuf -oL --'`, which I imagine tells the debugger to force line-buffering.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, all it took was for me to change to `debugCmd = "stdbuf -oL /usr/bin/libinput debug-events"`.  It works as I initially desired, if you can please add an answer below, I will gladly mark as the accepted answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in comments, this isn't a Go issue at all, but rather just needs the use of [the `stdbuf` command](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html#stdbuf-invocation) on GNU/Linux systems.  See also [this unix.stackexchange.com question and answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/192995/162084).  The general idea is to make sure that the program you run using `exec.Command` does not buffer *its own* output inappropriately.

(The stdbuf programs generally use `LD_PRELOAD` to insert alternative I/O buffering for stdin, stdout, and stderr, or may be built into the standard libraries on the OS.)